# Dynamic Pivot Table mysqli and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pivot-table

I am bit struggle where the mysqli and PHP using on the Dynamic Pivot Table, as I am able to get the static pivot table in PHP but not dynamic one.

I built a dynamic Pivot in the MySQL Workbench and it looks fine and it's perfect working.

[image: Workbench Screenshot]

The struggle is PHP, as I have tried to query multi, or statement out, both are failed as I understand multi-query is not recommended, but I am stuck at the moment.

as you can see the code I wrote for PHP

```
function get_all_records() {
    $conn = getdb();
    $Sql = "SET @sql = NULL;";
    $Sql .= "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT( 'MAX(IF(suo.date = ''', date, ''', suo.units_ordered, 0)) AS ', CONCAT('`',date,'`') ) ) INTO @sql FROM tbl_sku_units_order;";
    $Sql .= "SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ls.sku AS list_sku, 
    COALESCE(MIN(suo.sku), 'NotSold' )  AS sold_sku,  
    ', @sql, ' , 
    COALESCE( SUM(suo.units_ordered), 0 ) AS total_sold 
     FROM   tbl_list_sku AS ls
           LEFT JOIN tbl_sku_units_order AS suo 
                  ON suo.sku = ls.sku 
    GROUP  BY ls.sku 
    ORDER  BY total_sold DESC');";

    $Sql .="PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;";
    $Sql .="EXECUTE stmt;";
    $Sql .="DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;";

  $result = mysqli_multi_query($conn, $Sql);
   if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

       while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
           echo "<tr>
   <td>" . $row['list_sku'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $row['today_sold'] . "</td></tr>";
           }
        //  echo "<tr> <td><a href = '' class = 'btn btn-danger' id = 'status_btn' data-loading-text = 'Changing Status..'>Export</a></td></tr>";
        echo "</tbody></table></div>";
   } else {
       echo "<P class = 'text-center'>You have no recent QTY Daily Inventory</P>";
    }
}
```

and it not working at all.
also I like the Workbench tools export to PHP code but most of the important function is missing

```
$query = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT  CONCAT(         'MAX(IF(suo.date = ''',         date,       ''', suo.units_ordered, 0)) AS ',       CONCAT(\"`\",date,\"`\")    ) ) INTO @sql FROM tbl_sku_units_order";


if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($date);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        printf("%s\n", $date);
    }
    $stmt->close();
```

as this missing function is

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ls.sku AS list_sku, 
    COALESCE( MIN(suo.sku), "Not Sold" )  AS sold_sku,  
    ', @sql, ' , 
    COALESCE( SUM(suo.units_ordered), 0 ) AS total_sold 
     FROM   tbl_list_sku AS ls
           LEFT JOIN tbl_sku_units_order AS suo 
                  ON suo.sku = ls.sku 
    GROUP  BY ls.sku 
    ORDER  BY total_sold DESC');
```

Comment: A script for building and executing a pivot:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot

Comment: Thanks for this document, I know it's late but it great document to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be easier than you're making it. You don't need to use PREPARE and EXECUTE in the text protocol. And no need to query `INTO @sql` in SQL. Just format the query in PHP code and execute it.

```
// expand the expression so it's easier to see if parens are balanced
$Sql = "
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT 
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(IF(suo.date = ''', date, ''', suo.units_ordered, 0)) AS `', date, '`'
    )
  ) 
  FROM tbl_sku_units_order;";
$gc_result = $conn->query($Sql);
// always check for errors
if (!$gc_result) {
  echo "ERROR in SQL: $Sql\n{$conn->error}\n";
}
$gc_row = $gc_result->fetch_row();
$pivot_columns = $pivot_row[0];

// and check if this string is empty,
// because there might be no data to pivot
if (!$pivot_columns) {
    $pivot_columns = 'NULL';
}

$Sql = "
  SELECT ls.sku AS list_sku, 
  COALESCE(MIN(suo.sku), 'NotSold') AS sold_sku,  
  $pivot_columns,
  COALESCE(SUM(suo.units_ordered), 0) AS total_sold 
  FROM tbl_list_sku AS ls
  LEFT JOIN tbl_sku_units_order AS suo 
    ON suo.sku = ls.sku 
  GROUP BY ls.sku 
  ORDER BY total_sold DESC";
$pivot_result = $conn->query($Sql);
// always check for errors
if (!$pivot_result) {
  echo "ERROR in SQL: $Sql\n{$conn->error}\n";
}
```

Comment: Sorry didn't get back  to you, Thanks for code, however, the error is 'Call to a member function fetch_row() ' on the "$gc_row = $result->fetch_row();" so i have tweak on "$gc_row = $gc_result->fetch_row();" and still same but i will look around to find this error.

Comment: I fixed a couple of syntax errors in your SQL, for example one too many parentheses in the first query. Tip: Every time you run a SQL query, check that the result is not `false`. If it is, then log `$conn->error` because that will tell you what the error is. I left the error-checking code in your playground example. By the way, you should change your password now that you've put it on the internet. :-)

Comment: it ok, this SQL is playground as it not real as I am going leave it for few days then I will take it down, and I notice there is no change on a playground. apologies for hassle message.

Comment: Okay I made edits to the code in my answer above. See the comments in the code.

Comment: thank for your update, seems it displayed but all group as together, i am working on it now. to find to break date into colums, as you can see it http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/b7tm-46rt